Private NuGet Source Feed 401 Unauthorized - Rider / SourceTree (Git Credential Manager) -> after migrating Microsoft account domain
I've got recently account domain changed (e.g. from myName@myName.com to myName@notMyName.com) and everything is correctly set up in Microsoft Azure DevOps and I can login into Azure DevOps, everything works on browser, but now I've got 2 issues:

SourceTree Git Credential Manager opens up for login puproses and: I can select my desired (new) account -> type password -> window closes down and nothing happens
Jetbrains Rider returns always 401 (Unauthorized) for Nuget Restore

Any ideas how to solve it? I tried uninstalling (Git), deleting folders (.nuget & AppData/JetBrains) etc, nothing helps.


Log out from all your Microsoft accounts in all your browsers (but not "Log out from all devices" on your MS account settings - it won't probably help, but on your Azure DevOps site. And click "Sign out and forget" the account you want to remove (old one). Or if there are still issues, just clear all your browsers' data, cache & history etc.

Uninstalling cache folders for Nuget and Rider or reinstalling programs won't help. Maybe full Rider reinstall would help, but it's hard to achive (unless you want a full system reinstall). The simpliest way is to: Close all apps -> Run (some cache clearing): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders -> Download & Open Visual Studio -> Open the project you want -> Click Nuget Restore -> Close Visual Studio -> Open Rider.


But overall it's also a good idea to delete all cache folders, you would get 20+ GB of free space :)
